# React/RCTAssert.h file not found in react-native-matomo

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, matomo

Tried updating my RN to 0.62.2 and using the podspec command in README linked it to my project. But once trying to run the app, getting error
'React/RCTAssert.h file not found'
Tried various methods to link, clean the project. But none worked.
If I remove the import in RCTLog.h , it shows other dependencies are not found, so he base reason is the plugin.
Any idea on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me.

Pods-->BNFMatomo--> Search Header Search Paths --> Add "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" -->Change to recursive

Thanks to
https://github.com/BonifyByForteil/react-native-matomo/issues/47